# How to autofill a text area when a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am trying to have my text area automatically fill in when a checkbox is checked using JavaScript.

This is my view currently:

```
   .section
     .section_header Advanced Settings
     .panel.panel-primary
       .panel-body
           .form-group
             = f.check_box :hello, { label: "hello", checked: @user.hello }, '1', '0'

            = f.text_field :tag, value: @tag
```

I want to have the text field contain "hello" if the checkbox is checked and leave it blank if it is not.

How would I do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You have the framework for a question but lack evidence of trying to solve the problem yourself. We'd like to see your attempt at writing the necessary JavaScript, or at least show us where you researched this and explain why those pages didn't help. Currently, it looks like you didn't try and want us to write the code which is off-topic for SO. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can add inline JavaScript something like this, but you may want to extract it to a separate file:

```
.section
  .section_header Advanced Settings
  .panel.panel-primary
    .panel-body
      .form-group
        = f.check_box :hello, { id: 'hello_cb', label: "hello", checked: @user.hello }, '1', '0'
        = f.text_field :tag, value: @tag, id: 'tag_field'

:javascript
  let checkbox = document.getElementById('hello_cb')
  let input = document.getElementById('tag_field')
  checkbox.onchange = function() {
    input.value = checkbox.checked ? 'hello' : ''
  }
```

I also added IDs to elements for easy targeting, but you may be able to target them differently without touching your original HTML.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

(considering your checkbox id is `hello`, and your text_field id is `tag`)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hello').change(function(){
        if(this.checked){
            $('#tag').val('hello');
        } else {
            $('#tag').val('');
        }
    });
});
```